# Is it meaningful to distinguish a one-object category and its opposite?

Tags: category-theory

As in the title, for a category with only one object $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal C^{op}$ seems the same with the original one but I still believe there is a difference between them, can someone give an example where $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C^{op}$ play different roles?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider the natural numbers as a semigroup with binary operation
$x ⊕ y = x$. Then $0 ⊕ 1 = 0$ but in the opposite semigroup $0 ⊕ 1 = 1$!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathcal{C}$ corresponds to a monoid $M$ which is the set of morphisms $\hom(\cdot,\cdot)$. Let us write the multiplication by $\circ$. Then $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ corresponds to $M^{op}$ which is the same set of $M$ but with multiplication $x\circ' y=y\circ x$.

This is useful sometimes. For example, if $R$ is a ring, then $R^{op}$ is also a ring, known as its opposite ring. And a left $R$-module becomes a right $R^{op}$-module.

Answer (score 3):

Sure they're different. The have the same object and arrows, but composition is reversed. If $BM$ is a one-object category whose monoid of morphisms is $M$, then a functor $BM\to Set$ can be identified with a left $M$-set, while a functor $BM^{\mathrm{op}}\to Set$ is similarly identified with a right $M$-set.

The simplest example I can think of (although I think there should exist a four-element example) of a monoid non-isomorphic to its opposite is 
$$M=\langle a,b,c, z: ab=a, cb=c, ac=ca=z, ba=b, bc=b\rangle$$, and such that the generators are all idempotent and $z$ is an absorbing element. Any isomorphism between $M$ and $M^{\mathrm{op}}$ must preserve $z$, the unique absorbing element, and $b$, the unique element absorbing exactly two other elements of $M$ from the right, and so is either the identity or the 2-cycle exchanging $a$ and $c$. But neither function is a homomorphism. I think it should be easy to

Comment: Perhaps providing an example where $M$ and $M^{op}$ aren't isomorphic would be helpful (equivalently where the categories of actions aren't equivalent)

Comment: @Max Actually, Morita equivalent monoids need not be isomorphic, unlike the case of groups. Examples can be found here; the core difference is that monoids often have non-identity idempotents, so interesting identifications can happen under idempotent completion. That said, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh I went too fast in my head when reviewing the proof for groups, thanks for correcting that !

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the link: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02572973